# Why individual delete calls with delete on cascade?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, devart

I've got two tables with an 1:n relation (one `animal` has many `animal_events`) and a delete on cascade in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
   Id             INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY   AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Description    VARCHAR(512),
   Timestamp      TIMESTAMP       
);

CREATE TABLE animal_events (
   Id            INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY   AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Begin         DATETIME      NOT NULL,
   AnimalId      INT,
   Timestamp     TIMESTAMP,
   FOREIGN KEY animal_fk(AnimalId) REFERENCES animals(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So when I delete an `animal`, all the corresponding `animal_events` should be deleted also.
This is something that is done by the database, triggered by the delete on cascade clause whenever I delete an animal. **Correct?**

But in the sql trace I see many individual delete commands. 
**Why is the entity framework/devart doing this?**

```
DELETE FROM rfidfarm.animal_events WHERE Id = 1 
DELETE FROM rfidfarm.animal_events WHERE Id = 2 
DELETE FROM rfidfarm.animal_events WHERE Id = 3 

DELETE FROM animals WHERE Id = 1
```

Isn't this superfluous, since the database would take care of `animal_events` or is it just a bug in my EF setup/configuration?

---

**Updates**

Extract for the edml file

```
<Association Name="animal_events_ibfk_2">
  <End Role="animals" Type="Model.Store.animals" Multiplicity="0..1">
    <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
  </End>
```

If I use this test code, I see **many individual deletes**:

```
using (var uow = _modelFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
{
    var animal = uow.Animals.GetById(2);
    var animalEventCount = animal.AnimalEvents.Count;
    uow.Animals.Delete(animal);
    uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I use this code there is **only one delete** as hoped for:

```
using (var uow = _modelFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
{
    var animal = uow.Animals.GetById(2);
    uow.Animals.Delete(animal);
    uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Well that kind of depends on how you actually delete these records, and how you generated your DbContext (assuming EF database first).

Comment: I use 'DbSet.Remove(entity);'

Comment: Does your DbContext know about the cascade rules? Didn't you add the cascades after generating the DbContext?

Comment: As for the creation, I used the devart DbContext template to generate teh classes (database first).

Comment: @CodeCaster: The DbContext knows about the cascades, at least I see some `Action=Cascade` in the edml file. I didn't add any cacade rules after the generation.

Comment: What table engine do you use in MySQL? Innodb? Myisam? Sg else?

Comment: @Shadow: I use Innodb.

Comment: I've got different behavior if I access the animal_events before deletion (see my update in the question). Is lazy loading doing something here?